# Como organizar a pasta raiz de um site corretamente?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

gostaria de saber qual e o padrao a ser seguido e a melhor forma de organizar os arquivos do site corretamente, exemplo eu tenho uma pasta principal que e o nome do site e dentro dessa pasta tenho uma pasta css,js,img,fonts

para cada seção do meu site que eu criar (novo arquivo .html) devo criar um arquivo css e um js tbm? ou eu posso utilizar os msm arquivos js e css para todas as paginas que eu criar?

Comment: Seu site será estático ou dinâmico?

Comment: cara ainda n comecei a estudar nenhuma linguagem e back end entao sera estatico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa pergunta é bastante baseada em opinião, então corre o risco de ser fechada em breve.

Para sites estáticos, é bem comum você encontrar o formato:

```
├ audios/
├ css/
│   └ style.css
├ fonts/
├ images/
├ js/
│   └ main.js
├ vendor/
│   └ jquery/
│   └ bootstrap/
├ videos/
├ index.html
```

Isso se não tiver utilizando nenhuma ferramenta de gerenciamento de pacotes, como `npm`, `bower`, ou linguagens como `PUG`, `SASS`, `LESS`, `CooffeScript`, `TypeScript`, etc. Nesses casos a organização dos diretórios pode mudar.

Sobre os arquivos CSS e JS, é interessante que você mantenha tudo em apenas um arquivo, para se beneficiar do sistema de cache dos navegadores. Em imagens do template, tais como ícones que não são baseados em fontes, é interessante fazer o *sprite*.